# GCC implicit conversion does not work with QMap and QMap&

Tags: gcc, reference, implicit-conversion, qmap

How do I solve this:

> no known conversion for argument 5 from ‘QVariantMap {aka QMap}’ to ‘QVariantMap& {aka QMap&}’

gcc has this problem, MSVS does not, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert an instance of a class to a reference to an instance. You need to use the `&` operator on argument five in order to pass in a reference, which is apparently what is expected.